# Categorize orders into numbers

Tags: r

this is (maybe :) ) the last question for a longer period of time I need to solve for my boss, so please help me again (one last time ;) ) - I want to "categorize" the orders into classes by numbers:
"0" if the Item size AND color AND manufacturer is unequal to the personal most ordered size and color and manufacturer
"1" if the Item size is equal to the personal most ordered size
"2" if the Item color is equal to the personal most ordered color
"3" if the item manufacturer is equal to the personal most ordered manufacturer
"4" if the Item size AND color is equal to the personal most ordered size AND color
"5" if the Item size AND manufacturer is equal to the personal most ordered size AND manufacturer
"6" if the Item color AND manufacturer is equal to the personal most ordered size AND manufacturer
"7" if the Item color AND color AND manufacturer is equal to the personal most ordered size AND color AND manufacturer

Data:

```
DB <- data.frame(orderID  = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),     
orderDate = c("1.1.14","1.1.14","1.1.14","1.1.14","2.1.14",
  "2.1.14","2.1.14","2.1.14","2.1.14","2.1.14"),  
itemID = c(2,3,2,5,12,4,2,3,1,5),  
size = c("m", "l", 42, "xxl", "m", 42, 39, "m", "m", 44),
color = c("green", "red", "blue", "yellow", "red", "yellow",
   "blue", "red", "green", "black"),
manufacturer = c("11", "12", "13", "12", "13", "13", "12", "11", "11", "13")
customerID = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1),
mostorderedsize = c("m", "-", "42", "m", "m", "42", "-", "-", "m", "m"),
mostorderedcolor = c("green", "red", "-", "green", "green", "-", 
  "red", "red", "green", "green"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
mostorderedmanufacturer = c("-", "12", "13", "-", "-", "13", "12", "12", "-", "-")
```

Expected outcome:

```
DB$AAPP = c("4", "6", "5", "0", "1", "5", "3", "2", "4", "0")
```

Unfortunately I have no idea how to solve the problem- hope you guys are able to help me...

THX!

Comment: Unfortunately I need to add another column: mostorderedmanufacturer (the most ordered manufacturer)- changed the expected outcome:PLZ help me... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach:

```
DB <- transform(DB, AAPP = (as.character(size) == mostorderedsize) +
                             2 * (as.character(color) == mostorderedcolor))
```

The result:

```
   orderID orderDate itemID size  color customerID mostorderedsize mostorderedcolor AAPP
1        1    1.1.14      2    m  green          1               m            green    3
2        2    1.1.14      3    l    red          2               -              red    2
3        3    1.1.14      2   42   blue          3              42                -    1
4        4    1.1.14      5  xxl yellow          1               m            green    0
5        5    2.1.14     12    m    red          1               m            green    1
6        6    2.1.14      4   42 yellow          3              42                -    1
7        7    2.1.14      2   39   blue          2               -              red    0
8        8    2.1.14      3    m    red          2               -              red    2
9        9    2.1.14      1    m  green          1               m            green    3
10      10    2.1.14      5   44  black          1               m            green    0
```

---

*Update*

You can use this command for the updated question:

```
transform(DB, AAPP = round(1.3 * (as.character(size) == mostorderedsize) +
                        2.3 * (as.character(color) == mostorderedcolor) +
                        3.3 * (as.character(manufacturer) == mostorderedmanufacturer)))
```

Comment: Works-but how can I integrate the column AAPP in my existing data set? It´s only printing out the result, but I´m not able to intregrate it into my dataset

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner You can assign the result to `DB`, i.e., `DB <- transform(DB, AAPP = (as.character(size) == mostorderedsize) +
            2 * (as.character(color) == mostorderedcolor))`.

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner I added a command for your updated question.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
 indx <- DB[c('size', 'color')]==DB[c('mostorderedsize', 'mostorderedcolor')]
 DB$AAPP <- as.numeric(factor(1+2*indx[,1]+4*indx[,2]))-1
 DB$AAPP
 #[1] 3 2 1 0 1 1 0 2 3 0
```